# GLM: link function and error distribution relationship, intuitive explanation

Tags: distributions, generalized-linear-model, error, intuition

The very concise explanation of GLMs in my course describes the link function without saying much about the error distribution. From what I read in other places such distribution seems much more important than it would seem in my course.
For GLMs in one the most useful answers on this site I read
 *["The link function is the cumulative probability function that the error terms follow"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259683/understand-link-function-in-generalized-linear-model/259689#259689)*
I would be extremely grateful if someone provides an intuitive explanation of the above (for GLM), and of the actual importance/role of error distributions in general, beyond punctual and terse statements like those of my course (that just goes "to apply xzy we assume that the error is/has distribution ..." (no explanation of the why)
I notice only now a question that seems the same as mine (please correct if wrong), at [What difference (if any) exists between the Response Distribution and Error Distribution in GLMs?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92078/what-difference-if-any-exists-between-the-response-distribution-and-error-dist)

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48594/purpose-of-the-link-function-in-generalized-linear-model

Comment: In the link you posted I am unable to see the answer to my question,  it  speaks about link function modeling parameters of the distribution, every course says so no problem with that.  My questions are:  
1) intuitive explanation of why "The link function is the cumulative probability function that the error terms follow"   
2) importance of error distribution in general (if such a general question makes sense and can be answered it in a Q&A)   
Maybe the thread you posted answers that but I am unable to see it because of problems with 2)